# Why aren't div tables working on Firefox on a website served with WAMP?

Tags: html, css, html-table, wampserver

I can get regular table tags working fine, but I need them to be divs in order to easily let users adjust the size. I used the [converter tool here][1] to generate my div-table code. The demo on that site is working fine as is every other div-table I've seen on the internet. When I inspect the element of the div-table, there's nothing in the styling box. My borders are not showing up either. The rows all seem to be in the right position, but the cells within each row are arranged vertically instead of horizontally.

I suppose the problem is my WAMP 64bit 3.0.6 server. I'm running Apache 2.4.23, along with PHP 5.6.25. Please let me know what other information you need to diagnose my problem. I tried restarting the server as well as my computer, but to no effect.

Even though the regular table tags work fine, the site I'm making has a tabular layout, so I figured I'm supposed to use div-tables.

Here is a snippet with the exact same code that doesn't work on my home WAMP server:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* DivTable.com */

.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Link Aggregator Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/memewar.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test;</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How is the server you run going to impact the way the browser renders HTML?

Comment: I don't know, but that is the only difference between the website I made and the sites where div-tables are working fine. I just keep on reading that it's better to use div-tables instead of tables these days and I figured I'd go along with the trend.

Comment: Your server is **very** unlikely to be the issue here, Either the conversion has thrown an unclosed tag or something similar, possibly due to broken table mark-up. Either way, it is very hard for us to solve your problem without a concrete code example of what is happening see: [MCVE] . You would be better off writing the mark-up yourself, instead of relying on a converter tool. Tables are not evil, use them for tabular data, don't go using `div` to recreate a table if you actually have a table. Just don't use tables to lay out a page.

Comment: I just had a closer look at the converter tool, and its demo is doing exactly what I warned against. Generally I would not you a div structure to present a table like they do. Of course sometimes there are exceptions to the rule. Basically having seen that raised questions in my mind about the usefulness/validity of that tool.

Comment: I have to say that if you are using divs to create a table, you're doing it wrong. If this is tabular information, use a table.

Comment: But the layout of the website is tabular. It's not tabular information. It's supposed to be a grid of clickable links, and as a link gets more views, it's cell "grows larger" and takes over the page. Basically I want to ultimately have a website that works like reddit, but looks like the [milliondollarhomepage](http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/index_files/image-map.png).

Comment: Are any of your other styles working? Is the style sheet actually loaded? Check your path to your CSS resource. Furthermore, from your description a table, CSS or otherwise will probably not work for you anyway.

Comment: Everything else works fine. It's only the stuff with the tables that doesn't work. Can you suggest a better way to create what I'm trying to create?

Comment: You say it doesn't work in Firefox, so does that mean it DOES work in Chrome (or whatever other browser you can test with)? One problem with Firefox is that it has troubles with encoding mismatch between HTML and CSS files - if the one is in UTF-8 and the other is in UTF-16, the stylesheet won't load. So check all files and make sure they use the same encoding.

Comment: Is the site public? Can you provide an URL?

Comment: By the way, I also took a look at the conversion tools, and I'm not sure I trust a site that misspells "syntactically correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Lister was correct. It was an encoding mismatch issue. I feel like it hasn't been an issue in the past, but I can't argue with the results...